# running separate python programs with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to create a script that will run my other python programs. I am new to `subprocess` module so this is a bit confusing to me.

**project structure**

> ```
> /qe-functional
>    /qe
>       /tests
>          cron_functional.py
>          test_web_events.py
>    setup.sh
> ```

**cron_functional.py**

```
print(os.getcwd())
# print(subprocess.check_output('ls'))
runtag = "daily_run_" + datetime.today().strftime("%m_%d_%y")
testrun = "source ../../setup.sh; ./test_web_events.py -n 10 -t prf -E ctg-businessevent -p post {}".format(runtag)
cmd = testrun.split()
print(cmd)
subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

**output**

```
$ python cron_functional.py 
/Users/bli1/Development/QE/qe-functional/qe/tests
['source', '../../setup.sh;', './test_web_events.py', '-n', '10', '-t', 'prf', '-E', 'ctg-businessevent', '-p', 'post', 'daily_run_05_26_15']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cron_functional.py", line 11, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: `source` is a bash command, you probably need to add `/bin/sh` at the very beginning of your command that you pass to `subprocess.check_output`.

Comment: Additionally, using relative path names (`../../` and `./`) is a problem waiting to happen.  If you can the use absolute names or get directory names from the environment (like `HOME`).

Comment: Specify a shell on your call: `subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)`  Note the security hazard warning in the documentation.

Comment: Do you realise that you are passing parameters to `setup.sh`?

Answer (score 1):

`source` is an internal shell command, not an executable.  What you want is not to run one `source` command with 11 arguments, but a one-liner shell script.  You need to pass the whole script as one string to be interpreted by the shell.

```
subprocess.check_output(testrun, shell=True)
```

You haven't said what `setup.sh` does.  If it's setting up environment variables and changing the working directory, consider doing that within Python instead.  Then you can run

```
subprocess.check_output(['./test_web_events.py', '-n', '10', …, '-p', 'post', runtag])
```

… without involving the shell.